# Special JSON parsing in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I want to build an iOS app for which I need to create an array out of this JSON String that shows only the contents:

```
[ {"content":"hello"}, {"content":"hi"}, {"content":"how are you?"} ]
```

The result should look like this:

```
["hello", "hi", "how are you?"]
```

How can I do that in **Swift**?

This is my code in the ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mList = "[{"content":"hello"},{"content":"hi"},{"content":"how are you?"}]"
        let data = mList!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: There are countless examples of how to parse JSON in iOS and Swift. Please do some basic research and try something. When you get stuck with a specific implementation, please update your question with relevant code and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for your fast reply! I have spent hours on how to do this and still haven't come to an answer. My problem is that there is no "header" in the beginning of my JSON string and all I can find are tutorials for arrays with "headers". I'd also be happy for any recommendations for websites etc and will try to improve my question.

Comment: You get an array with three dictionaries, each with a single key/value pair. You want an array with the three values. Do achieve this, you do the unthinkable: Write your own code. One line, actually.

Comment: The problem has already been solved. Thank you anyway though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let mList = "[{\"content\":\"hello\"},{\"content\":\"hi\"},{\"content\":\"how are you?\"}]"
let JSONData = mList.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var json: Array<AnyObject>!
do {
    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? Array
} catch {
    print(error)
}

var resultArray = [String]()
for item in json {
    if let content = item["content"] as? String {
        resultArray.append(content)
    }
}
print("resultArray: \(resultArray)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str:String = "[\"xx\",\"yy\",\"zz\"]"

let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

do {
    var jsondata = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! NSArray
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

(sorry, example now works in playground)

Comment: thanks, this code works but its not what I needed. I want to get only the "content" values (from the Json data of my question above) to display!

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet above won't compile because you need to escape the interior quotes.

This does what you want:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation

func arrayFromJSON(jsonString: String) -> [String]?
{        
    if let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    {
        if let array = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [[NSObject:AnyObject]]
        {
            return array.map { $0["content"] as! String }
        }
    }
    return nil // If the string isn't valid JSON
}


let jsonString = "[{\"content\":\"hello\"},{\"content\":\"hi\"},{\"content\":\"how are you?\"}]"

print(arrayFromJSON(jsonString))
```

Comment: I know this should be avoided but thank you. This really helped me.

Comment: Never decode JSON to or from a string. JSON always comes in as data, not string, so the only time you would convert a string is when someone has stupidly converted the data to a string. And what the hell is "allowLossyConversion" doing there? If there are any problems, then the conversion MUST, ABSOLUTELY MUST fail.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm not aware of a way to decode json to something other than a string. How would you do this?

Comment: @gnasher729 Please explain why you think that JSON should never be decoded from a string. JSON is a text format, so accepting a string as input seems unproblematic, particularly in Swift where the encoding is not in question.

As for `allowLossyConversion: false`, I'm not sure what your problem is with that except possibly that the argument is redundant. I'll edit the answer.